# How to host Angular Universal 9 on Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, webpack, deployment, angular-universal

I have 2 applications in: Angular Universal 9 & standard Angular 9 and I have to host them on the same App Service (Stack: .NET 4.7 with node.js 12.13.0).
Currently an app with Angular 9 is working but I have a problem with deploying an app with Angular Universal 9.

Comment: I have to struggle to deploy the last three days. Can you share some more info?. @Mariusz D.

Comment: I have asked the question. Its same scenario can you tell me more details
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63932339/how-to-publish-angular-9-unviersal-with-net-core-application-in-azure-app-servi

@Mariusz D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue, I had to change in:
- servet.ts path to dist folder with index.html
- web.config rule to dist-server/main.js instead of server.js

Comment: Hi, (according to this question https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1527 ) I'd bet that you are MDzyga in githun, am I right?
Could you give more details on what you had to change? I've been struggling my mind during las few hours because I was deploying my angular 8 app targeting server.js (without dist folder) but it is impossible to make it work targeting server/main.js 
Thank you in advance...

Comment: @Juan Did you find any solution. We have also facing same issue. If u find any solution can you share?.

Comment: Yes, indeed I wrote an answer but the answer was deleted because it was the same answer to another very similar question. let my try to add my answer again. 

I wrote an answer here but it was deleted becuase it was exactly as this ither answer( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61574428/angular-9-universal-deployment-woes/62228308#62228308 ) 

Also, I wrote an article (in spanish) and you'll find some hints at the end but the point is to review paths in server.ts and web config. https://juan-garcia-carmona.blogspot.com/2020/08/angular-9-i18n-ssr.html

Comment: @Juan that article not covered the deployment process. Thanks for your response. you have solved me many prblms from ur response. Can you tell me about deploy process.

Comment: I really woried about this deployment process stuck in last four days. I have seen many answer but none of them covered entire part. I have used Asp.Net core with Angular Application i need to publish. Can you tell me some details.

Comment: I have asked question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63932339/how-to-publish-angular-9-unviersal-with-net-core-application-in-azure-app-servi

@Juan